# compare java hash map key with the string

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to compare a string with key value of a hashmap.

```java
private Map<String, Integer> map1= new HashMap<>();
 map1.put("User1" , 100);
 map1.put("User2" , 200);
 map1.put("User3" , 300);

public void test(String user, int size) {
    for(String key : map1.keySet()) {
        if (key.equals(user)) {
          System.out.println("yes");    
        }else{
          System.out.println("no"); 
        }
    }
}
```

yet my code is not working and i get answer no even when user is in map, any idea what is the problem?

I changed the code a bit but the given answer is still no:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class A1 {

 private static Map<String, Integer> map1= new HashMap<>();


 public static boolean test(String user, int size) {
    for(String key : map1.keySet()) {
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(user)) {
          return true;  
        }
    }
    return false;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        map1.put("User1" , 100);
        map1.put("User2" , 200);
        map1.put("User3" , 300);
        if(test("User1" , 100)){
                  System.out.println("yes");    
        }else{
          System.out.println("no"); 
        }
    }
}
```

@Jason ty

```java
map1.containsKey(user)
```

worked.

Comment: Where are you adding entries to the Map?

Comment: A simpler (and faster) alternative would be to use `map1.containsKey(user)`

Comment: it's not in my code up there but it is in my original code , i believe something is wrong with my if condition.

Comment: what data is added to map  post code

Comment: let me try @Jason

Comment: If you are asking for help about why your code isn't working, please post enough of your code to be able to demonstrate the problem. As it stands, the problem is that your map doesn't contain any data. Please edit your question to show the code that adds data to your map.

Comment: Please clearly specify what you mean by "not working"

Comment: Ok, now you've got data. Can you show the code that is calling `test(...)`? What values are being passed? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Your code doesn't look optimal, but somehow right. You are iterating the `keySet` while comparing each key to the user name. Possible reasons for a user not to be found are: (1) the user does not exist in the map or (2) the user exists, but in a different case which would basically be (1) again, if you don't want to apply `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean test(String user, int size) {
    for(String key : map1.keySet()) {
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(user)) {
          return true;  
        }else{
          return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

This loop always returns on its first iteration, so it will only return true if the first key matches.

It's the same as:

```
Iterator<String> it = map1.keySet().iterator();
return it.hasNext() && it.next().equalsIgnoreCase(user);
```

If you want to keep searching until you find a matching key, remove the `return false;` inside the loop.